# Ubuntu hung at purple screen startup

Tags: ubuntu

I was running a program. My computer just randomly restarted. Now at the purple screen where I choose which entry I want (Ubuntu), I cannot do anything. It says

"The highlighted entry will be executed automatically in 10s."

However, it does not change. Whenever I hold shift to go to recover mode or whatever, it does not let me. Any ideas?? I can't get my work done since my computer won't start!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: https://www.startpage.com/do/search?query=Ubuntu+hung+at+purple+screen+startup&cat=web&pl=chrome&language=english

Comment: version 14.04..when i do get to bios, i cant navigate or anything either

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120096/ubuntu-hangs-at-purple-screen

Comment: @Moab the solution there does not work. it just goes to the purple screen even when i hold shift. I also cant edit the commands before booting. It freezes i think and i cant do anything

Comment: Make a post on the Ubuntu forums then, they have more experience than we do. If you figure it out, you can post it as an answer to your own question here.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't navigate in bios, the problem is probably larger than just Ubuntu. This is strange, though. You usually need to press a certain key to get to bios, and if your keyboard works, bios should work. Nonetheless, I would recommend plugging in another keyboard as soon as it gets to the boot menu and trying to use that. My computer occasionally gets stuck on Grub(that purple screen), and using a different keyboard solves it.

Comment: but if I am clearly able to get to the bios by pressing a certain key, why would another keyboard solve it?

Comment: I don't know, but I've had a similar problem and it worked. I think that in my case, the system started to ignore any currently connected keyboards after a certain point(unplugging and reconnecting the one I had probably would've worked too, but that was a laptop  so..). Also, this would still be an important step in the troubleshooting process because it could prove that the problem is in the computer. What I CAN say is that the problem isn't with Ubuntu and it isn't with Grub(since BIOS doesn't work). So if it isn't the keyboard, it's a hardware problem(as BIOS is build into the motherboard)

Comment: So you think it could be the motherboard? I am able to get to bios by pressing delete so i feel like the keyboard must be working to some extent.